# While loop is repeating once more

Tags: c++, c, input, char

I don't know whats wrong in my code it is repeating once more.

```
do { 
         scanf("%c", &operacao);
        //Tratamento de erro (Validando a informacão vinda do usuário
        if ((operacao != '*') && (operacao != '+') && (operacao != '-')) {
            printf("---------------------------------------\n");
            printf("*****       MENSAGEM DE ERRO      *****\n");
            printf("---------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Você digitou um valor inválido!\n");
            printf("Por favor, digite + para soma, - para subtração * para multiplicar ou / para dividir!\n");
        }
    } while ((operacao != '*') && (operacao != '+') && (operacao != '-'));
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: 1. print operacao after reading it. 2. What type is operacao? printing the value will help you understand while loop.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should consider `cin >> c` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf`.  The `scanf` returns the number of parameters *satisfied* or -1 if there is an error.  Don't trust the Users to input correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following statement

```
scanf(" %c", &operacao);
      ^^^
```

Otherwise white space characters (as for example the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter) are also read.

Comment: Thx for a tip - I have already solved the problem. Thx for your attention anyway.